# compare two fields not in the same column for all lines

Tags: loops, awk, compare

My question is as presented here:
[compare two fields not in the same column in consecutive lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13851614/compare-two-fields-not-in-the-same-column-in-consecutive-lines/55078857#55078857)

But, the difference is I would like to do that for all lines and not just consecutive ones, using awk.

**Thanks for any help!**

Edit:
For example ,
I want to mark the lines where $2==$4(in another line) and $3==$5(in another line)
the starting file is:

```
c3 1 63072 1 63072
c3 18109 29942 13125 25007
c3 18105 26056 14949 22881
c3 19004 26038 18102 25145
c3 14949 22881 18105 26056
c3 18102 25145 19004 26038
c3 18090 26038 13562 21528
c3 18964 26028 18532 25565
c3 14162 21991 10076 17931
c3 18964 26038 9921 17008
```

and the result I wish for:

```
c3 1 63072 1 63072 Not_Equal
c3 18109 29942 13125 25007 Not_Equal
c3 18105 26056 14949 22881 Not_Equal
c3 19004 26038 18102 25145 Not_Equal
c3 14949 22881 18105 26056 Equal
c3 18102 25145 19004 26038 Equal
c3 18090 26038 13562 21528 Not_Equal
c3 18964 26028 18532 25565 Not_Equal
```

because the 5th line is as same as the 3th and the 6th is the same the 4th.
(and I wish this comparing would be made for sections where **the first column is the same** ***- Example below***)

**Clarification:**

```
c3 1 63072 1 63072 Not_Equal
c3 18109 29942 13125 25007 Not_Equal
c3 18105 26056 14949 22881 Not_Equal
c3 19004 26038 18102 25145 Not_Equal
c3 14949 22881 18105 26056 Equal
c3 18102 25145 19004 26038 Equal
c3 18090 26038 13562 21528 Not_Equal
c3 18964 26028 18532 25565 Not_Equal
a3 1 63072 1 63072 Not_Equal
a3 13125 25007 18109 29942 Not_Equal
```

So even though the last line is the same as the second, because the first column is different it is not equal

Comment: Please post samples in clear text inside CODE TAGS, do not give links/images/attachments for samples. Also do add your efforts which you have put in order to solve your own problem in your post too.

Comment: Ok , thanks for the note!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you please try following once(tested in given samples only).

***Without checking condition for 1st column:*** column 1st with c/a values were NOT considered in this code's Input_file.

```
awk '
FNR==NR{
  a[++count]=$0
  next
}
{
  for(i=1;i<=FNR;i++){
    split(a[i],array," ")
       if($3==array[1] && $2==array[4] && i!=FNR){
           print $0,"Equal"
           next
       }
  }
}
{
  print $0,"NOT Equal"
}'   Input_file  Input_file
```

***How does the code work:***

- It will read the Input_file 2 times.
- It will save complete line's value into an array in first run of Input_file.
- Then in 2nd run it will run a loop for each line from 1 to till value of row(so by doing this it should cover all lines TO all lines check.
- Have added a SPECIFIC CONDITION(Make sure while checking if 3rd column of current line is equal to 1st item of array(which is actually 1st fields value we saved in 1st run of Input_file) AND 2nd field is equal to 4th item of array(which is 4th columns of lines stored in 1st run of Input_file). If we see carefully your very first line has `1 63072 1 63072` where 1st field is equal to 3rd field and 2nd to 4th SO I added condition that this match should NOT be performed on same line, to avoid these kind of "FALSE POSITIVES" here.

Output will be as follows.

```
1 63072 1 63072 NOT Equal
18109 29942 13125 25007 NOT Equal
18105 26056 14949 22881 NOT Equal
19004 26038 18102 25145 NOT Equal
14949 22881 18105 26056 Equal
18102 25145 19004 26038 Equal
18090 26038 13562 21528 NOT Equal
18964 26028 18532 25565 NOT Equal
14162 21991 10076 17931 NOT Equal
18964 26038 9921 17008 NOT Equal
```

***EDIT(with adding $1 to condition check):*** Since OP wants to check $1(with c/a etc values) too so adding that condition check now too.

```
awk '
FNR==NR{
  a[++count]=$0
  b[$1]=$1
  next
}
{
  for(i=1;i<=FNR;i++){
    split(a[i],array," ")
       if(b[$1]==array[1] && $4==array[2] && $2==array[4] && i!=FNR){
           print $0,"Equal"
           next
       }
  }
}
{
  print $0,"NOT Equal"
}'  Input_file  Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
c3 1 63072 1 63072 NOT Equal
c3 18109 29942 13125 25007 NOT Equal
c3 18105 26056 14949 22881 NOT Equal
c3 19004 26038 18102 25145 NOT Equal
c3 14949 22881 18105 26056 Equal
c3 18102 25145 19004 26038 Equal
c3 18090 26038 13562 21528 NOT Equal
c3 18964 26028 18532 25565 NOT Equal
a3 1 63072 1 63072 NOT Equal
a3 13125 25007 18109 29942 NOT Equal
```

---

---

---

***GENERIC Solution(s) to read the Input_file from both(up to down AND down to up):***

Adding 1 more GENERIC solution(a bit enhancement of above answer). I just thought if `A=B` is TRUE then `B=A` is also TRUE. Means OP's example checks only from 1st to last lines. Means if line 3rd's elements(1st column is EQUAL to 3rd column of line 5th) Then it should be TRUE for 5th line's 1st column to 3rd line 3rd column condition, so now they BOTH should be written as EQUAL, if this could help you then try following.

***Without checking condition for 1st column:*** Column 1st with c/a values were NOT considered in this code's Input_file.

```
awk '
FNR==NR{
  a[++count]=$0
  next
}
{
  for(i=1;i<=count;i++){
    split(a[i],array," ")
       if($3==array[1] && $2==array[4] && i!=FNR){
           print $0,"Equal"
           next
       }
  }
}
{
  print $0,"NOT Equal"
}'  Input_file Input_file
```

***EDIT(with adding $1 to condition check):*** Since OP wants to compare $1(with c/a etc values) too so changed solution as per that too now.

```
awk '
FNR==NR{
  a[++count]=$0
  b[$1]=$1
  next
}
{
  for(i=1;i<=count;i++){
    split(a[i],array," ")
       if(b[$1]==array[1] && $4==array[2] && $2==array[4] && i!=FNR){
           print $0,"Equal"
           next
       }
  }
}
{
  print $0,"NOT Equal"
}'  Input_file  Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
c3 1 63072 1 63072 NOT Equal
c3 18109 29942 13125 25007 NOT Equal
c3 18105 26056 14949 22881 Equal
c3 19004 26038 18102 25145 Equal
c3 14949 22881 18105 26056 Equal
c3 18102 25145 19004 26038 Equal
c3 18090 26038 13562 21528 NOT Equal
c3 18964 26028 18532 25565 NOT Equal
a3 1 63072 1 63072 NOT Equal
a3 13125 25007 18109 29942 NOT Equal
```

Comment: Wow! Thank you so so much!! Another little question, does it work for only the same first column? meaning, for groups of same first columns? can I just add to the condition if:  && $1==array[1]?

Comment: Thank for the response! I'll bold that part on my question above.

Comment: @user11176119, I added 1 more solution too, where it checks file up to down and down to up so if 5th line is TRUE with 3rd line's elements similarly 3rd line should also be TRUE, if it helps you then let me know?

Comment: About the edit, thank you for trying to improve the answer! Appreciated very much! However, I want only the second and on line to be written as equal, so I can take only the "NOT Equal" lines, meaning exclude the "duplicates"

Comment: OK, I did as I wrote in the first comment to your answer and it worked!! THANK YOU SO MUCH!

Comment: @user11176119, Glad that it helped you and happy to have nice words from you on weekend :) cheers and happy learning on this GREAT SITE SO.